# How to change the text style in message body in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Some keyboard app can change the text style in any message body? Do they attach the font with? Or how they do it?

For easier understanding...

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the two rows above the numbers are not supplied by the keyboard, but instead are supplied by the chat/messaging app that you are using. How have you determined that they come from the keyboard?

Comment: @CommonsWare You can try "Facemoji Keyboard" or "FancyKey Keyboard" and many others Keyboard app in the Play Store can do this job! They can change text style chat/messaging even in gmail body text!

Comment: iirc they must be ascii characters.

Comment: OK, then, they may be using https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard on Android 7.1 and higher.